# How can I confirm I'm playing the current version of Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I feel like I am encountering bugs that were reported as fixed in the most recent patch. Is there a way I can confirm what version of the game I'm running?  I can't seem to find an "About" menu anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

If you connect to Steam and play the game, it will automatically patch up to the latest version.  The only way you could be playing an old version is if you're playing in offline mode.  The version number should be listed on the main menu screen that comes up after the opening movie:

[image: main screen screenshot]

The current version at this time is 1.0.1.217.  You should be able to see the latest version at any time by going to [this thread](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?89117-Patch-Notes) on the official forums.